# How can I add a button to the Eclipse IDE that will turn on or off a certain preference?

Tags: eclipse, button, ide, preferences

Some context first: I'm in charge of *purifying* the (abominable) source code for an old, huge Java application. Eclipse's code style cleanup tool does a good bit of work, upon which I can then rewrite the extant source code into something less awful, but I keep running into an annoyance: I have the "organize imports" save action turned ON (see Preferences → Java → Editor → Save Actions → Organize imports), but I would rather be able to turn it OFF while I am working on a particular file, and turn it back ON when I'm done with it, to ensure the file gets fully cleaned up.

Routinely turning the mentioned preference on or off on command through the standard dialog windows is less than straightforward (and one can get lost as to its current state as well). It would be much more comfortable to define a custom button in the IDE that I could simply click to turn this particular preference on and off, and know its current state just with a quick glance... but I'm at a loss on how to program such a button.

Comment: You would have to write an Eclipse plugin for this and it looks like it would have to use 'internal use only' APIs.

Comment: You can organize imports later on the package or on the whole project, if it helps.